# Sub-Gaussian random variables and convex ordering

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, convexity, measure-concentration

Suppose that $X$ is a $1$-sub-Gaussian real-valued random variable, i.e. for all $t \in \mathbf{R}$, it holds that $\log \mathbf{E} \exp \left( t X \right) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} t^2 $.

1. Does there always exist a constant $\sigma = \sigma_X \geqslant 1$ such that (writing $G$ for a standard Gaussian variable), $X$ is dominated by $\sigma_X \cdot G$ in the convex ordering?
2. If so, can $\sigma_X$ be taken independent of $X$?

An example, to show that there is hope: consider the case of (normalised) Bernoulli random variables, and write $X \overset{\mathrm{d}}{=} \mathsf{Ber}(p) - p $.

The Kearns-Saul inequality shows that

\begin{align}
\log\mathbf{E}\exp\left(t \cdot X \right)&\leqslant\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{1-2\cdot p}{2\cdot\log\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)}\right) \cdot t^{2}.
\end{align}

With some work, one can show that $X$ is majorised in the convex order by $\sigma(p) \cdot G$, where $\sigma (p) =\frac{p\cdot\left(1-p\right)}{I_{\gamma}\left(p\right)}$ and $I_\gamma = \phi_\gamma \circ \Phi_\gamma^{-1}$ is the Gaussian isoperimetric function. This implies the (weaker) estimate on the MGF

\begin{align}
\log\mathbf{E}\exp\left(t \cdot X \right)&\leqslant\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{p\cdot\left(1-p\right)}{I_{\gamma}\left(p\right)}\right)^{2}\cdot t^{2},
\end{align}

which only loses at most a constant factor of at most $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \approx 1.25$ in the implied $\sigma$, which happens when $p = 1/2$. So, in this (very) limited setting, the result holds.

Comment: Could you add what is meant by convex order? $Ef(X)\le Ef(Y)$ for every convex $f$?

Comment: @jlewk yes, exactly as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $X$ is subgaussian with subgaussian norm less than $1/\sqrt 2$ then
$$P(|X|>t)\le 2 e^{-t^2} \le K P(|Z|>t)
$$
for some numerical constant $K>1$, thanks to lower bound on $P(Z>t)$.
For instance, $K=4$ is achievable thanks to Formula 7.1.13 in *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with. Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables* by Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun, which gives
$P(|Z|>t)\ge 4e^{-t^2/2}/(\sqrt{2\pi}(t+\sqrt{4+t^2})$.

Once the above inequality holds for some $K>0$,
the following is essentially a trick in Lemma 4.6 of *Probability in Banach Spaces* by Ledoux and Talagrand.

First, let us study the case where $X$ is symmetric in the sense that it is equal in distribution to $\epsilon |X|$ where $\epsilon$ is a Rademacher random variable independent of $|X|$.

Let $\delta\sim$Bernoulli$(1/K)$ independent of everything else so that $K E[\delta]=1$. Then by independence
$$
P(|\delta X|>t) = P(|X|>t)  / K \le P(|Z|>t)
$$
for all $t>0$ which grants stochastic dominance of $|X|$ by $|\delta Z|$, i.e., there is a rich enough probability space such that $X,\delta,Z$ have the same distribution as before and $P(|X|\delta \le | Z|)=1$.

Let $F$ be convex. Denote by $E_\epsilon$ the conditional expectation given $(\delta,|X|,Z)$ (i.e., integration with respect to the law of $\epsilon$ only). The function
$$a \mapsto E_\epsilon[ F(a \epsilon |Z|)]$$
is convex and it attains is maximum over $a\in[-1,1]$ at an extreme point, either $-1$ or $1$. With $a=X\delta/|Z|$ this gives almost surely $E_\epsilon[F(\epsilon|X|\delta)] \le E_\epsilon F(\epsilon |Z|)$. Taking expectation and using Jensen's inequality with respcet to $\delta$ noting that $E[\delta|Z,X]=1/K$,
$$
E[F(X/K)] = E[F(\tfrac1K \epsilon|X|)] \le
E[F(\delta \epsilon|X|)]
\le
 E[F(\epsilon |Z|) = E[F(Z)].
$$
where the two equalities follow thanks to $X=^d \epsilon|X|$
and $Z=^d \epsilon |Z|$. This solves the question if $X$ is symmetric.

If $Y$ is subgaussian but not symmetric, the definition of subgaussianity used in the question implies $E[Y]$ so that if $Y'$ is an independent copy of $Y$,
$E[F(Y-E[Y'])]\le E[F(Y-Y')]$.
Now $X=Y-Y'$ is subgaussian (with twice the subgaussian norm) and we may apply the result to the symmetric random variable $X$.
This gives
$E[F(Y/8)]\le E[F(Z)]$ for any  $1/\sqrt 2$-subgaussian random variable $Y$.

Comment: I will take a look at the reference in Ledoux-Talagrand, thanks. I'm not so clear about the final point; all of the variables which I consider are centred, and so $P(X>0)$ is never $1$.

Comment: I also wonder whether your assertion that $F(|X|\delta) \leq F(|Z|)$ secretly uses monotonicity of $F$ in some form?

Comment: If $F$ is twice differentiable, the first and second derivatives of $a\to F(|aZ|)$ are $|Z| F'(|aZ|)$ and $Z^2 F''(|aZ|)$ if $a>0$, and  $-|Z| F'(|aZ|)$  and $Z^2 F''(|aZ|)$ if $a<0$. This proves convexity in this case and I do not see a secret use of monotonicity. You are right regarding the final point, I had in mind the definition of subgaussian rv that does not require zero-mean, but your definition with the MGT requires it. I will think about it.

Comment: I modified the answer to obtain $E[F(Y/8)]\le E[F(Z)]$ for any  1-subgaussian random variable $Y$.

Comment: I think that the first paragraph is not quite right, since the tails of the Gaussian decay slightly faster than implied by the Chernoff bound. Still, the broad strokes of the proof still work. thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for correcting the first paragraph. Indeed the variance of $Z$ needs to be a little larger than the sub-gaussian norm of $X$ to compare the tails for all t, for instance $2e^{-t^2}\lesssim P(|Z|>t)\asymp \frac1t e^{-t^2/2}$ holds if there is no $1/2$ in the leftmost exponential. The answer is fixed.